# Multiple field: Mongodb Duplicate key: {..., null}

Tags: mongodb, duplicates

Email is set to unique for accountType = email, username is also set to unique for accountType = username. Mongodb sends this for accountType = username. The key is not { username: "username" }

```
"err": "E11000 duplicate key error collection: painPoint.users index: email_1 dup key: { email: null }",
{
    "error": {
        "index": 0,
        "code": 11000,
        "keyPattern": {
            "email": 1
        },
        "keyValue": {
            "email": null
        }
    }
```

Email key is correct, but depending on which account I create first.

```
    "err": "E11000 duplicate key error collection: painPoint.users index: email_1 dup key: { email: \"damianemerah1@gmail.com\" }",
    "error": {
        "index": 0,
        "code": 11000,
        "keyPattern": {
            "email": 1
        },
        "keyValue": {
            "email": "damianemerah1@gmail.com"
        }
    }
}
```

I want both to return the correct keyvalue, I don't know what might be causing this since both fields is set to unique in the schema definition.

My Schema

```
import mongoose from "mongoose";

const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  email: {
    type: String,
    unique: [true, "Email already exists"],
    required: [
      function () {
        return this.accountType === "email";
      },
      "Email is required",
    ],
  },
  username: {
    unique: [true, "Username already exists"],
    type: String,
    required: [
      function () {
        return this.accountType === "username";
      },
      "Username is required",
    ],
  },
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: [
      function () {
        return this.accountType === "email";
      },
      "Name is required",
    ],
  },
  accountType: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    enum: ["username", "email", "google"],
  },

  password: { type: String, required: true },
  since: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
  injuries: [{ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "Injury" }],
});

export default mongoose.models.User || mongoose.model("User", UserSchema);
```

Who can help with solution?

Answer (score 1):

In the schema both 'email' and 'username' are tagged unique, so there will be an index created on the collection in the mongod server that will enforce that uniqueness.

When a field is not included in a document, the index will use `null` as the value of that field when building the index entry.

Since the 'email' field is not required when 'accountType' is anything other than "email", it will not always be present.  Since the unique index will not permit more than 1 entry with `null` as the value, this means you can have only 1 document that does not contain an email address.  Likewise for 'username'.

You can work around this by declaring the indexes to be sparse.  That means that if the field is not present in the document, there will be no entry in the index for that document.

You can specify that by explicitly passing the index options in the schema for each field:
`index: { unique: true, sparse: true }`